Scaled bump function supported on the unit disk converges to the delta function
Consider the antiderivative $$g(x)=\int_0^x e^{-1/t}\mathbf{1}_{t>0}dx$$. Note the support of $g$ is $[0, \infty)$. $g$ is smooth and $g^{'}(x)=e^{-1/x}\mathbf{1}_{x>0}$ which is a smooth non analytic function. Consider $\phi(v)=c_ng(1-\|v\|^2)$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\phi$ is a compactly supported on smooth function on the closed unit disk, and we set $c_n$ so that the integral of $\phi$ is $1$. Now my question is can we say

If $\phi_\epsilon(v)=1/\epsilon^n \phi(v/\epsilon)$, then as $\epsilon\to 0$, do we have $\phi_\epsilon\to \delta_0(x)$? $\delta_0(x)$ is the delta measure supported on $0$, and the convergence is happening in the Schwartz space.
If $f$ is any continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then do we have $f\ast \phi_\epsilon\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets?

Apparently it is known this is true when instead of $g$ we take its derivative $e^{-1/x}\mathbf{1}_{x>0}$. I'm interested in showing this for the antiderivative. I would also appreciate a proof of 1. in the case of $e^{-1/x}\mathbf{1}_{x>0}$, because I haven't been able to show it.
